# Having join or multiple resultsets

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following 2 tables with a one to many relationship. The table ORDER and ORDER_DETAILS. I am using C# to call a stored procedure to do some processing but eventually it should return the orders with its corresponding details.

So the question is which one of the 2 below is more optimized.

1. Select the orders and joining with the order details, and then having the data in c#.
2. Having 2 result sets, 1 orders and the order order details, then building up the data in c#.

My guess is that since the join will repeat the same columns in the order table each order details, the 2nd option is best.

What are your views on the above.

Comment: Optimized for what? Data transfer? Database performance? And how much data are we talking about here?

Comment: Trying to avoid the repeated column values is a premature optimisation.  That's simply how SQL Result Sets look, and is hasn't been a problem in the last three+ decades.

Comment: Do you want ALL the orders, or just a few of them?

Comment: Your description is simply too vague for anyone to make useful comments without guessing. Ignoring the efficiency aspect (which can't be measured until you have actual requirements), you need to focus on two different things. First is a good description of what "do some processing and return the orders" actually means. Second is what your application intends to do with this information and the format it needs to most efficiently consume the information.

Comment: And if you don't want / like "repeated columns" then change your queries to not produce the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

@Steve asked the right question. You need to clarify that.

But I would in most of cases go for first option. Joining both the tables at database end and selecting only necessary columns for the front end.

In this way you need to transport lesser amount of data and in normal scenario it should be faster than getting data from both tables and building it in front end. But without knowing your proper context it might not be the best possible solution.